# Why won't the MySQL image be created even though it's specified in the docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, debugging

I got my project to run locally (home page appears) using Docker on my new M1 Macbook Pro.

However, I'm unable to run `php artisan migrate` because it looks like the image for MySQL is missing despite it being specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

After running `docker-compose up -d --build` followed by `docker ps` (to check images), the MySQL image doesn't exist.

The database credentials in the `docker-compose.yml` file match what's inside the `.env` file, just FYI so we can rule out this being the possible issue.

Why's this happening and how can I fix it so I can connect to my local MySQL db?

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: sammy
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    working_dir: /var/www/
    environment:
      - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - lahmi

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    platform: linux/x86_64
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker-compose/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./docker-compose/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    networks:
      - lahmi

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 8005:80
    depends_on:
      - db
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - lahmi

networks:
  lahmi:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Remove `platform` from your `docker-compose.yml` file, and run `docker-compose build db`. Then simply do `docker-compose up -d` and after that (wait 10 seconds) run `docker-compose logs db` and share those logs please.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I did what you said but `docker-compose logs db` returns nothing, not sure why.

Comment: Try `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` and retry to do `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: @matiaslauriti After running `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` then `docker-compose up -d` followed by `docker-compose logs db` - it still returns nothing.

Comment: @sp92 comment the volume line `./docker-compose/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf` just to check your conf is not destroying the process.

Comment: @matiaslauriti upon running `docker-compose exec app bash` - I'm automatically navigated into the `/var/www` directory.  Then, I try to navigate to the `mysql` directory via: `cd docker-compose/mysql/` - The `my.cnf` file only contains two lines: `general_log = 1` and `general_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/general.log
`.

Comment: when you run `docker-compose build db`, do you see everything is being built correctly ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti oh, when I run `docker-compose build db` - it returns nothing.  I think that's the issue.  Sorry I didn't mention that earlier, I thought that was expected ‍♂️

Comment: The `db` service doesn't have a `build:` block, so `docker-compose build db` won't do anything.  If you run `docker-compose up db` (without a `-d` option; start only the database service, in the foreground) does anything interesting come out in the logs?

Comment: @DavidMaze ok so for the heck of it, I ran `php artisan migrate` and it worked!  Not sure how though.  It must've been one of the commands above.