# Why isn't MySQL image being created in my docker?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, debugging, docker-compose

After running `docker-compose up -d --build` followed by `docker ps` (to check images), the MySQL image doesn't exist.

When pinging my API endpoint, I get this error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate fro` users`where`email `= test@test.com)`

The database credentials in the `docker-compose.yml` file match what's inside the `.env` file, just FYI so we can rule out this being the possible issue.

I have a strong suspicion it's because no MySQL image exists when running `docker ps`.

To try to rectify this, I tried running `docker-compose up testApp` - it didn't fix it because I ran  `docker ps` and the MySQL image still doesn't show up

Why's this happening and how can I fix it so I can connect to my local MySQL db?

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: sammy
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    working_dir: /var/www/
    environment:
      - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - lahmi

  testApp:
    image: mysql:5.7
    platform: linux/x86_64
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker-compose/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./docker-compose/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    networks:
      - lahmi

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 8005:80
    depends_on:
      - db
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - lahmi

networks:
  lahmi:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Here's the output of `docker-compose up testApp`:

```
[+] Running 1/0
⠿ Container testApp-testApp-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
Attaching to testApp-testApp-1
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13 23:04:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.36-1debian10 started.
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13 23:04:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13 23:04:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.36-1debian10 started.
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13 23:04:41+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD are for configuring a regular user and cannot be used for the root user
testApp-testApp-1  |     Remove MYSQL_USER="root" and use one of the following to control the root user password:
testApp-testApp-1  |     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
testApp-testApp-1  |     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
testApp-testApp-1  |     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
testApp-testApp-1 exited with code 1
```

Logs via `docker-compose logs`:

```
testApp-testApp-1  |
testApp-testApp-1  | ERROR: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
testApp-testApp-1  | command was: "mysqld --verbose --help"
testApp-testApp-1  |
testApp-testApp-1  | mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13T23:57:57.676571Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010095] [Server] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13T23:57:57.690269Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
testApp-testApp-1  |
testApp-testApp-1  | ERROR: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
testApp-testApp-1  | command was: "mysqld --verbose --help"
testApp-testApp-1  |
testApp-testApp-1  | mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13T23:58:20.142446Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010095] [Server] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
testApp-app-1     | [13-Nov-2021 23:58:20] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13T23:58:20.156224Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
testApp-app-1     | [13-Nov-2021 23:58:20] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
testApp-app-1     | [13-Nov-2021 23:58:20] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
testApp-app-1     | [13-Nov-2021 23:58:20] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
testApp-app-1     | [13-Nov-2021 23:58:20] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
testApp-app-1     | [13-Nov-2021 23:58:20] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
testApp-app-1     | 172.18.0.3 -  14/Nov/2021:00:01:42 +0000 "POST /index.php" 500
testApp-nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
testApp-nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
testApp-nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
testApp-nginx-1   | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
testApp-nginx-1   | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
testApp-nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
testApp-nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
testApp-nginx-1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
testApp-nginx-1   | 2021/11/13 23:58:21 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
testApp-nginx-1   | 2021/11/13 23:58:21 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.4
testApp-nginx-1   | 2021/11/13 23:58:21 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.3.1 20210424 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424)
testApp-nginx-1   | 2021/11/13 23:58:21 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.47-linuxkit
testApp-nginx-1   | 2021/11/13 23:58:21 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
testApp-nginx-1   | 2021/11/13 23:58:21 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
testApp-nginx-1   | 2021/11/13 23:58:21 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
testApp-nginx-1   | 2021/11/13 23:58:21 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
testApp-nginx-1   | 172.18.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2021:00:01:44 +0000] "POST /api/register HTTP/1.1" 500 15495 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4"
```

Comment: Are you [reposting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958143/why-wont-the-mysql-image-be-created-even-though-its-specified-in-the-docker-co?noredirect=1#comment123665755_69958143)?

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes, sorry about that... you may close this question if you like.  I've been hammering at this almost all day but to avail :(

Comment: @gp_sflover that was originally my question :) despite my last comment saying that it works, it turns out that it doesn't as the mysql docker image is still missing.  This post right here, the one you've just commented on, has more detail.

Comment: What exactly do the logs tell you? `docker-compose logs` or `docker logs <container>`

Comment: @Jaquarh check my latest comment on my original post, I've posted the `docker-compose logs` :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is super straight forward... you are using `root` as a normal user... read the logs...

```
testApp-testApp-1  | 2021-11-13 23:04:41+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD are for configuring a regular user and cannot be used for the root user
testApp-testApp-1  |     Remove MYSQL_USER="root" and use one of the following to control the root user password:
```

You also told me in your original question that there were no logs... it was empty...

Comment: yes but before these logs weren't showing up at all for some reason, but now they are.  now I have a clue on what to do